# Switchcompat not displaying the Switch

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I am trying to use the latest appcompat which was updated for material design in my app to show the switch view as displayed in Lollipop(http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), the problem is the switch is not getting displayed. My SDKmin is 14 and max is 21. I am using the below code in the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_scheduler"
    tools:context="com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel.SchedulerUI">

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="switch"
        app:showText="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="start"
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole layout? What view is the SwitchCompat being added to?

Comment: No..there is also button within the layout. It is within linearlayout. I have added the entire layout

Comment: Any views on how to get this to work?

Comment: Try removing `app:showText="false" ` and use `android:text=""`

Comment: This is not working..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had same problem today but somehow it switchcompat worked in my sample. I think that there is problem with app style, it parent should be set to:

```
Theme.AppCompat
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have set, and it doesn't work on any pre-KitKat device. The view just doesn't show up at all - no text, no switch, nothing.

Comment: I have the same problem! I have set the activities Theme to Theme.AppCompat (well I have tried with all availebale Themes, like Theme.AppComapt.Light.DarkActionBar) unfortunately it does not work!

Comment: Guys to need v7 21 compat lib, also if I remember correctly setting just theme is not enough - you also need to set primary/primaryDark/accent colors for your new theme. It works for me.

Comment: how did you solve this? I tried setting the Theme.AppCompat to my Activity but I do not see the Switch widget

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the support library, but you have to ensure that the context for your layout inflater is a themed one.

1. Make sure your activities theme Theme.AppCompat as parent
2. If you use inflate SwitchCompat in ListView or RecyclerView you have to ensure that the LayoutInflater you instantiate and use in your adapter is created with the themed context. You can retrieve the themed context by calling: Activity.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()

Comment: Wow...just wow. I used the applicationContext as I am using it all the time. To inflate it with the activity context did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: This was apparently it... Pisses me off though, since it's not suitable for me to use activity context... +1

Comment: I wasted a day with that, I repeat a whole DAY! What @JacksOnF1re says was my problem too. When I was initializing the adapter, I was passing `getApplicationContext()`, now I changed it to MyActivity.this and it works like a charm...Strage thing is that I had it right and working for some time, but I made some changes at some point...

Comment: Changing the getApplicationContext to MyActivity.this worked for me:)

Comment: also, same issue when you initialize your View with RestrictedContext rather than regular Activity context. See more about different context types and restrictions here: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: I was getting the layout inflator to inflate the SwitchView from the application context, I changed it to activity.getLayoutInflater(). It worked!

Comment: @JacksOnF1re : Same. Couldn't Google just give in a word about this in Docs? I have wasted hours on this. DAMN.

Comment: A BIG Thanks to you!

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you can utilize

`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`

On your control

Comment: when drawing over other apps you will need to set this as well. FIY

Answer (score 3):

I had a custom theme in my **styles.xml** and I forgot to specify its parent:

*name="CustomTheme.switchState" **parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"***

Something like this:

**custom_linear_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.switchState" />

...
</LinearLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
...

name="CustomTheme.switchState" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorOne</item>
        <item name="android:textOn">On</item>
        <item name="android:textOff">Off</item>
    </style>

...
</resources>
```

Comment: This solution only worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you've encountered https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78262

Copy the layout and pngs, fix the nine-patch, and you should be fine.